# Почему в Delphi "Trace into" открывает какой-то ассемблерный код?

Tags: delphi, отладка, ide

В delphi 10 при запуске Trace into открывается новая вкладка и дебаггер проходится по какому-то ассемблерному коду. Раньше работал как надо, может быть надо в настройках что-то поменять?

Comment: Попробуйте удалить *.rsm файлы которыю сгенерировались в папку `bin`. Если не помогло - очистите проект, проверьте конфигурацию (должна быть `Debug`)

Comment: Возможно, [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7749212) совет поможет Вам.

Comment: «Раньше работал как надо» - как именно?